# tmux vim display issue on parenthesis

Tags: vim, tmux, ubuntu-16.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and this problem returned. I vaguely recall fixing it on 14.04 but I can't remember how.

I've got the tmux window split into two panes. vim is running in the left pane displaying a file. If the vim cursor is on a parenthesis of any sort when I switch panes, the parenthesis will become a caret on the display though it isn't changed in the file. Switching back to vim and moving the cursor will cause it to redraw correctly.

Outside of tmux TERM is gnome-256color. Inside tmux TERM is screen-256color.

Any ideas on what is causing this?

**Update**

I can make it happen by simply changing focus using Alt-Tab. That is, I don't need to switch tabs in tmux. Simply moving focus around the screen will cause it to happen.

**Update2**

It turns out it was unrelated to gnome-terminal so I removed references to it.

Comment: When I try this, I see parenthesis being matched and it is highlighted. Is that the same in your case?

Comment: Yes, the parenthesis are highlighted before I switch panes.

Comment: When I do `:NoMatchParen`, I see that this issue is gone. Can you confirm?

Comment: Confirmed. I also note that when I comment out Plugin 'tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events' it goes away.

Comment: I think we can use some autocommands to do `NoMatchParen` on leaving vim window and set it back on focusing vim again. Let me also look at the plugin you mentioned. I'll post an answer after that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was happening because of vim's parenthesis highlighting on matching.

From `:help matchparen`

> The functionality mentioned here is a standard-plugin.
>   This plugin is only available if 'compatible' is not set.
>
> You can avoid loading this plugin by setting the "loaded_matchparen" variable:
>
> ```
> :let loaded_matchparen = 1
> ```
>
> The plugin installs CursorMoved, CursorMovedI and WinEnter autocommands to
>   redefine the match highlighting.
>
> ```
> :NoMatchParen :DoMatchParen
> ```
>
> To disable the plugin after it was loaded use this command:
>
> ```
> :NoMatchParen
> ```
>
> And to enable it again:
>
> ```
> :DoMatchParen
> ```

You can use autocommands to toggle this.
Something like

```
:autocmd FocusLost * :NoMatchParen
:autocmd FocusGained * :DoMatchParen
```

Should work.

You can use [tmux-focus-events.vim](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events) plugin if your console vim doesn't support these autocommands

Also take a look at [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33289/can-i-make-tmux-tell-vim-when-its-pane-loses-focus) in unix stachexchange.

Comment: Yep. But I needed `autocmd FocusLost * :NoMatchParen` in my .vimrc. Note the asterisk. Same for the FocusGained.

Comment: Oops almost missed that. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: As I noted in Update2 above, this issue is unrelated to gnome-terminal so I removed that misinformation from the question. I could see it in the terminal app on my chromebook.